# docker compose build with npm nexus registry in private network using github action and tailscale

Tags: github-actions, cicd, tailscale

I have a nexus registry located in private network
i need docker-compose build in github action that can build a dockerfile which could be interactive /accessible to nexus

I've done on

- created tailscale network, joined and expose my nexus registry (in k8s) to tailnet
- the nexus registry is listening on specific domain eg: example.com
- after register nexus k8s service to tailscale following [this](https://tailscale.com/kb/1236/kubernetes-operator#annotations) we had nexus in tailnet domain: `<servicenamene>.tailxxxxx.ts.net`

I've setup github action like below

```
        steps:
            - name: Tailscale
              uses: tailscale/github-action@v2
              with:
                oauth-client-id: ${{ secrets.TS_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID }}
                oauth-secret: ${{ secrets.TS_OAUTH_SECRET }}
                tags: "tag:k8s"
                version: 1.56.0
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2
            - run: docker login -u xxx -p ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }} xxx.xxx.io
            - run: |
                .... docker-compose build ...
```

The `Dockerfile` looks like below:

```
###

FROM node:$NODE_VERSION as builder

ARG NEXUS_NPM_TOKEN
ARG NEXUS_CERT_FILE

RUN npm config set //<servicenamene>.tailxxxxx.ts.net:8080/repository/npm-xxx/:_authToken $NEXUS_NPM_TOKEN  \
  && npm config set @psa:registry http://<servicenamene>.tailxxxxx.ts.net:8080/repository/npm-xxx/ 

###
```

however seem like nexus doesn't accept request that had host header don't match with `nexusHttpHost` or `$NEXUS_HTTP_HOST`

any idea?

Comment: More detail is needed about how it's failing. A couple questions: what does "the nexus registry is listening on specific domain" mean? How did you configure that and what did you configure it to? What's the error you're seeing on the nexus side and/or the docker build side?